# selenium webdriver 3.0.1 geckodriver error for firefox

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to execute a ruby script that i found. It took me a bit too setup ruby and selenium webdriver 3.0.1, and now i get an error that it cant find geckodriver. I also downloaded geckodriver but i'm stuck and cant find how too add it to the "Path" it is talking about. Also mozilla says that i dont have to do anything, if i have selenium 3 or above have instaled. This is the error message that i get:

C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.1/lib/selenium webdriver/firefox.rb:58:in `driver_path': Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

if anyone can help me how to proceed please let me know 
best regards,
DarkdevelCoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the geckodriver.exe to your path as suggested:

Control Panel->System->Advanced system settings->Environment variables.

Comment: that worked now i have a lot more errors to fix but that means i made some progress :) at least that error is gone anyways

Answer (score 0):

- First download and unzip the geckodriver compatible with your selenium-webdriver version https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html# .
- Second,  in "Environment Variable" in the section "System Variables"  editing the "path" variable creating a new entry pointing to the new "geckodriver" directory.
- Finally restart the command prompt after modifying the environment variable.

Maybe the last past could be the trick.